# Run a JavaScript function from a php if

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to run JavaScript using PHP variables the code have PHP if statement and if true javascript will execute but the script using a second PHP variable.

```
<?php
   if ($time_close_option == 1){
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
      // close the div in $timeoutdiv secs
      echo 'window.setTimeout("closePromoSpace();",' <?php echo $timeoutdiv;?>);';
      echo 'function closePromoSpace()
      {
          document.getElementById("promospace").style.display=" none";
      };';
      echo'</script>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `$timeoutdiv` as a string, not a number. Try

```
<?php if ($time_close_option == 1) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // close the div in $timeoutdiv secs
    window.setTimeout(closePromoSpace(), <?php echo $timeoutdiv;?>);
    function closePromoSpace()
    {
        document.getElementById("promospace").style.display=" none";
    };
</script>
<?php  } ?>
```

Notice that we can clean the code up a lot by not using the `echo` statements, but by switching between php and html contexts.

Comment: its work perfect in FF and Chrome, but in IE it's not, Where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($time_close_option == 1)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'function closePromoSpace()
    {
        document.getElementById("promospace").style.display="none";
    }';
    echo "window.setTimeout(closePromoSpace, $timeoutdiv);";
    echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain the code what and how it is doing that to be more educative?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    if ($time_close_option == 1)
     {?>
       window.setTimeout(closePromoSpace, '<?php echo $timeoutdiv; ?>');
       function closePromoSpace()
       {
         document.getElementById("promospace").style.display = "none";
       }
    <?php
     } ?> 
</script>
```

Try this one